# Dome Light Fixture Screw - Won't Screw Back In

Tags: light-fixture

I have a dome light fixture. The little holder to remove it was stuck so I used pliers to turn it. The whole screw came out with it. Now the screw won't go back into the fixture. I assume it's strip, but it looks like there are threads in there still. What can I do?
[image: Light cover and screw]

[image: Light fixture]

[image: Closup of hole]

Comment: Why do you assume it's stripped? That's unlikely. Take the knob off the shaft, thread the shaft into the fixture base a few turns, and put the dome back on. Turn the knob (and indirectly the shaft) until lightly snug.

Comment: You might have to drop the fixture down to line up the shaft.  Some fixtures have a locking screw that will have to be loosened to screw the shaft back into the fixture which would explain why you needed pliers to remove it.

Comment: loosen the two Philips heads screws, rotate slightly CCW to remove fixture from ceiling. With it down, you can re-attach the stem while holding the nut hiding in the base plate. I would superglue or thread lock it at that point. Once stem is re-attached,  replace fixture by reversing the steps, then slide on the shade and screw on the retaining knob.